# Cannot get past smart boot manager

Tags: boot

I had Ubuntu mate loaded and decided to load Ubuntu instead
Could not boot from cd so installed smart boot manager
now I cannot get past the smart boot manager and
it will not accept any bootable cd, no matter how I create it

The Laptop is not dual boot

I cannot even get to Packard Bell recovery feature

I have an old Packard Bell easynote laptop that I decided to use Linux on

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.heise.de/download/product/smart-bootmanager)(unfortunately it is in german only) Smart Boot Manager won't boot Linux just like that. However, that shouldn't be a problem. Configure your BIOS(/UEFi) to boot from the optical drive first.

Comment: Many years since you could install `Smart Boot Manager` to hard disk, and expect a usable behavior  : Worked here with P-ATA disks till ~2009. ... Version 3.7-1 → Year 2001 → http://btmgr.sourceforge.net/about.html ( The site was updated 2001 )

Comment: I have tried that but nothing works